# Clear inside div A is clearing the float of div B, which is outside of div A

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

This is a problem I've had several times when trying to create layouts with a sidebar.

I made an example here: http://samutz.com/div.html

#content has stuff inside it that needs to float and then clear within #content only. But when I try to clear inside #content, it clears the #sidebar's float as well, despite #sidebar being outside of #content.

Comment: What browser? It looks good to me in Opera..

Comment: have you tried the answers yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option A:**

1. Remove clear:both from #cleared
2. Wrap #floating inside another div, give the new div `overflow:hidden; zoom:1;`

If this messes up #content text, put the text inside this new div:

http://medero.org/clear2.html

Explanation for overflow technique: http://work.arounds.org/clearing-floats/

**Option B:**

You can also absolutely position the sidebar but you might have to mess with min-heights if it  becomes long.

**Extra:**

If you need to contain the sidebar with your main wrapper:

http://medero.org/clear3.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm going with option A.

Comment: Is this still true?  I've run across this problem and I was sure I had solved it a different way in the past; but it's been a while and this is the only thing I can get to work now.

Comment: broken links, please fix